# Hibernate spring-data-jpa repository save detached entity tree @OneToMany

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three entities related with one to many:

Order (one):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="order")
public class Order implements Serializable {
    [...]
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List <OrderDetail> orderDetail;
    [...]
}
```

Order detail (many):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orderDetail")
public class OrderDetail implements Serializable {
    [...]
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order order;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List <OrderDetailRow> orderDetailRow;
    [...]
}
```

Order detail row (many):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orderDetailRow")
public class OrderDetailRow implements Serializable {
    [...]
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_detail_id", nullable = false)
    private OrderDetail order;
    [...]
}
```

I produce detached objects tree, let's say Order with one OrderDetail where ID of an Order and ID of an OrderDetail are **matched with ones existing in database** and a few OrderDetailRows (I want these objects to be created so their id==null so it is generated by sequence) under OrderDetail.

Then I issue entityManager.merge(order) and Hibernate is trying to set OrderDetail id to 0 which is resulting in data integrity violation exception.

NOTE: after issung entityManager.merge I see that resulting managed object tree is pretty much ok - OrderDetailRows objects have their ids generated correctly. I see an error when Hibernate is trying to flush so transaction can finish

What am I doing wrong?

Stacktrace from where "update orderDetail set id=? where ID=?; " is issued:

```
"http-apr-4086-exec-3@10191" daemon prio=5 tid=0x52 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:61)
      at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.writeIndex(OneToManyPersister.java:251)
      at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.insertRows(OneToManyPersister.java:192)
      at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:102)
      at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
      at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
      at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
      at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
      at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
      at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
      at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
      at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
      at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.save(Unknown Source:-1)
```

Comment: Can we have also the error stack please ?

Comment: Added to description stack trace from where "update orderDetail set id=? where ID=?; " is issued. Id is being set to 0. This is resulting with constraint violation.